# The Process Cannot Access The File Because It Is Being Used By Another Process...Any Ideas?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using the following code snippet to copy/backup database

```
Public Sub backupData()
        Try

            Dim s As StreamWriter

            Dim portfolioPath As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory
            'MsgBox(Application.UserAppDataPath)
            If Not Directory.Exists(LIC.My.Settings.BackupDirectory) Then

                Directory.CreateDirectory(LIC.My.Settings.BackupDirectory)

                File.Create(LIC.My.Settings.BackupDirectory & "\LIC.Mdf").Close()

                File.Create(LIC.My.Settings.BackupDirectory & "\Backup log.rtf").Close()

                s = New StreamWriter(LIC.My.Settings.BackupDirectory & "\Backup log.rtf", True)

                s.WriteLine("This backup was initially taken on - " & Date.Now)

                s.Flush()

                s.Close()

                FileCopy(portfolioPath & "\LIC.mdf", LIC.My.Settings.BackupDirectory & "\LIC.Mdf")

                s = New StreamWriter(LIC.My.Settings.BackupDirectory & "\Backup log.rtf", True)

                MsgBox("New directory and backup file created")

            Else
                FileCopy(portfolioPath & "\LIC.mdf", LIC.My.Settings.BackupDirectory & "\LIC.Mdf")

                s = New StreamWriter(LIC.My.Settings.BackupDirectory & "\Backup log.rtf", True)

                s.WriteLine("This backup was latest updated on - " & Date.Now)

                s.Flush()

                s.Close()

                MsgBox("Back up completed successfully")

            End If



        Catch ex As Exception

            Dim MessageString As String = "Report this error to the system administrator: " & ControlChars.NewLine & ex.Message

            Dim TitleString As String = "Data Backup Failed"

            MessageBox.Show(MessageString, TitleString, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End Try
    End Sub
```

But i get an error ***"The Process Cannot Access The File Because It Is Being Used By Another Process"***Any Idea How Can I Copy/Backup The Files??

Comment: If the file is looked you can't access it. The reason in this case is probably because it could be changed while you are reading it. To backup the database it's better to run a backup sql script on the sql server instead of manually trying to copy the file

Comment: @Mharlin I tried SMO but backup fails..i tried it numerous times ..no luck..so now i am trying it this way.

Comment: Is the question you really want answered how to backup SQL Server db? And this was just one of the ways you tried to do it? You could delete this question and post a new one instead with the steps you tried so far

Comment: You can't. You can't access files that are in use by another process. That doesn't mean it's impossible to back up SQL Server database files, but it does mean that your proposed approach is a non-starter. Update your question with details of the *actual* problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to copy the file unless you first shut down the SQL Server service.

Having said that, there is really no reason to use SQLDMO or the above method to back up the database; it can be done with a simple Transact SQL command:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO DISK = 'MyDatabase.bak' WITH FORMAT
```

This will back the database up to SQL Server's default backup directory (which I believe you specify at installation).

There are large number of options available with the backup command and [this MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191304.aspx) is a very good starting point for learning more.